# Windows 8 Libraries shorcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to my Libraries folder.

The only way I found was creating a shortcut of Libraries on Desktop and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. But I hate that! Why shouldn't be a shortcut for the mostly used folder? and why should I make my Desktop messy for just assigning a shortcut?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution if you have pinned the explorer onto your taskbar:

Close all open windows of the explorer, then hold shift and rightclick the explorer-icon on the taskbar. Choose **Properties** and assign a shortcut.

This works as the explorer opens up in the Libraries folder by default.